# Firestore (python) listener finished script instead of listening for changes

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to setup a firestore on_snapshot listener on python.
However, when I run the program, it finishes running without doing anything, let alone listening.

What am I missing?

I tried to get a one-time read i.e .get() and it worked so I know it is not a package / credentials issue.

```py
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

cred = credentials.Certificate("serviceAccountKey.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()

doc_ref = db.collection(u'someCollection').document(u'someDoc')

def on_snapshot (doc_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    for doc in doc_snapshot:
        print(u'New doc data: {}'.format(doc.id))

doc_watch = doc_ref.on_snapshot(on_snapshot)
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you trying to run this code as a script, which seems to be terminated before the callback function is executed. So try to let the `doc_watch` object live long enough.

For instance, use `sleep`:

```py
from time import sleep

import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

cred = credentials.Certificate("serviceAccountKey.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()

doc_ref = db.collection(u'someCollection').document(u'someDoc')

def on_snapshot (doc_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    global count
    for doc in doc_snapshot:
        print(u'New doc data: {}'.format(doc.id))

doc_watch = doc_ref.on_snapshot(on_snapshot)

sleep(3)

doc_watch.unsubscribe()
```

And do not forget to `unsubscribe()` at the end  ;).